# Visual Studio - Remove whitespace between methods

Tags: visual-studio, whitespace, code-formatting

Call me picky, but I prefer each of my methods to have a single line break between them. Is there any automatic way to configure VS to trim the number of line breaks between methods. e.g.

```
public void AMethod() 
{
    //code
}
//one line break
public void AnotherMethod()
{
    //code
}
```

Often through a variety of factors I end up with several lines between methods, during re-factoring say.

```
public void AMethod() 
{
    //code
}
//one line break
//oh noes, more whitespace
//and a third one :s
public void AnotherMethod()
{
    //code
}
```

Is there any way to trim space between methods down to 1 line (similar to say CTRL+E+D)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a quick replace (CTRL-H) and replace "\n\n" with "\n".  Make sure you set the options to use regular exceptions.  Depending on the number of spaces, you might have to do this more than once.

Comment: Yeah nice idea, except that as you say I'd need to effectively make such a replace dynamic due to the number of lines which may be present. I suppose I could write a macro to replace \n\n with \n, then \n\n\n with \n and so on, the number of lines needing replacing doesn't often extend beyond 5-6, give or take how brutally the class has been refactored!

Comment: Having \n\n will reduce all even number spaces by half.  So having four would reduce to 2 and odd numbers would skip the last space until the odd amount is reduced to 1.  So you could keep the same replacement expressions and click replace more than once instead of writing multiple expressions.

Comment: For a macro, you could just loop the replacement expression.  5 times should definitely give you your result.